# How can I raise an attached event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I would like to create an attachable Panel event that fires when `Panel.OnVisualChildrenChanged` is called :

```
public class PanelObserver {
    public static readonly RoutedEvent VisualChildrenChangedEvent;

    static PanelObserver( ) {
        VisualChildrenChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "VisualChildrenChanged",
            RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof( RoutedEventHandler ),
            typeof( Panel ) );
    }

    public static void AddVisualChildrenChangedHandler(
        DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler ) {
        //Something needs to be done to d so that when OnVisualChildrenChanged is called,
        //it will fire handler.
        ( d as Panel )?.AddHandler( VisualChildrenChangedEvent, handler );
    }

    public static void RemoveVisualChildrenChangedHandler(
        DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler ) {
        //Something will likely need to be done to d here as well...
        ( d as Panel )?.RemoveHandler( VisualChildrenChangedEvent, handler );
    }
}
```

The use case would be pretty straight forward

```
<Grid myns:PanelObserver.VisualChildrenChanged = "SomeEventHandler" />
```

Ideally the event would be raised each time `Panel.OnVisualChildrenChanged` was called. What would I need to add to the `AddVisualChildrenChanged` method ( and it's antipode ) to make this happen, if it's possible? If that's not how to accomplish this, then what is the proper method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to fire `Panel.OnVisualChildrenChanged` via an attachable Panel event.
Instead, you can derive from any `Panel` class and override `OnVisualChildrenChanged`, then declare another event.

For example:

```
public class ObservablePanel : Panel
{
    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
    {
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
        VisualChildrenChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public event EventHandler VisualChildrenChanged;
}
```

The reasons why you can't do it via an attachable Panel event:
1. `Panel.Children` property is a `UIElementCollection` which doesn't expose any events to catch if it "changed".
2. `Panel.Children` property is readonly so you cannot set it to a custom derived implementation of `UIElementCollection` which will expose "changed" events.
3. `Panel.OnVisualChildrenChanged` is `protected` so you can only access it on a `Panel` derived class.

Comment: thanks. This is so stupid. It seems like a pretty significant oversight to not let some method of detecting changes to panel contents by the .Net team.